# Adjust speed on jQuery UI accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery UI accordion of which I need to urgently change the speed/duration of the animation before the site goes live.

```
$(".faq-accordion > div").accordion({ header: "h4", collapsible: true, active: false, speed: "fast", });
```

Editing the speed in this line doesn't affect anything.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1e6z2ubp/3/) for full code.

The show all/hide all buttons open the accordion at a much faster speed than when they are individually clicked.

I need to speed up the animation of the accordion so both are the same speed if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [the accordion API](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-animate) you'll see that there's no option called *speed*, you need to use `animate`. The equivalent to a duration setting of `fast` for [`slideUp` and `slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/), in milliseconds, is `200`, so you can just use that as a number value:

```
$(".faq-accordion > div").accordion({
    header: "h4", collapsible: true, active: false,
    animate:200
});
```

Here's your fiddle updated with this: http://jsfiddle.net/z3Lx1o0y/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the speed at a more granular level in the slideUp/slideDown function
e.g.

```
$('.applying div div').slideDown(1000);
```

Try tweaking this.